# is simple a filler in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary, sentence

> Things just simply don't work

is **simply** a filler in that sentence ?

by filler i mean that the meaning of the sentence is the same with or without it

(i know this is not formal english, but i need to know the meaning)

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that it isn't a filler. 
It carries with it the connotation of it being: clear, obvious.
It at least changes the tone, and implication of the sentence.